# VGA signal out of range

Tags: vga

## Signal Not In range

When I installed Ubuntu server on my server (*HP Proliant DL380 G4*) I found that when I booted it after install I had to press 
 ctrl + alt + f1-6 to get to the terminal where something would show up. However when I got to the CLI I logged in and I installed LightDM and xfce4, when I did this and I pressed f8 I got stuck out of the terminal and my tv blacked out showing only a message (**"Invalid Format"**) so I switched to an old monitor and it said (**"Input signal out of range: Please switch to 1920 x 1080 @60 Hz"**). How do I fix this?
Please note:
I can't see as it has no built-in screen
I can't access anything graphical because when I try it blacks out
I can't see the terminal it also blacks out now
Also, I can't SSH into it as it isn't setup
I don't know the IP address either

Comment: If you want a graphic environment, why did you install Ubuntu Server?

Comment: I was trying to create a Counter-Strike server for me and my friends

Comment: I also tried Ubuntu Desktop

Comment: AFAIK a graphic environment is not a requisite for Counter-Strike. Also, Ubuntu Server comes with OpenSSH preinstalled.

Comment: If you can't see the screen, can't see the terminal, can't access via SSH, wouldn't it be easier to just start your install over from scratch?

Comment: I've already reinstalled multiple times though